# Return value evaluation of a stored function inside a loop with let variable

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

To my understanding, if the loop variable of a for loop is defined with **var**, then any change on that variable is applied globally. for example:

```
var printNumTwo;
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  if (i === 2) {
    printNumTwo = function() {
      return i;
    };
  }
}
console.log(printNumTwo());
```

In the above code, 3 will be printed into the console. Because in the last iteration the variable *i* will equal to 3. Therefore when printNumTwo is called, the update *i* will be returned.
However if I use **let** this is not the case and the following behavior happens:

```
let printNumTwo;
for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  if (i === 2) {
    printNumTwo = function() {
      return i;
    };
  }
}
console.log(printNumTwo());
```

The above code will print 2.

```
let printNumTwo;
for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  if (i === 2) {
    printNumTwo = function() {
      return i;
    };
    i = 3;
  }
}
console.log(printNumTwo());
```

however, the above code prints 3.
What is the reason for this?

source: [The first two code blocks are from here.](https://www.freecodecamp.org/learn/javascript-algorithms-and-data-structures/es6/compare-scopes-of-the-var-and-let-keywords)

Comment: Because you are calling `printNumTwo()` after assigning `i` with 3.

Comment: @kiner_shah I know. same thing also happens in the second code block (i++ in the update section in for loop ) but the answer is 2.

Comment: @MohammadbagherSoltani **Ah!** That's the source of misunderstanding. I've updated [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70769478/157247) to explain it. (Short version: The update is done to the `i` at the beginning of the next loop iteratoin, not the end of the current one.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first example, `var` scopes `i` to the function, so at the end of the loop `i++` changes `i` from `2` to `3` and the loop stops. The **only** `i` is now `3` and `printNumTwo` returns `i` which is `3`.

In the second example `let` scopes `i` to the block, so the function assigned to `printNumTwo` closes over it. The **last** time the body of the loop runs, `i` is `2` and `printNumTwo` returns `i` which is `2`. (A new `i` is created with the value `3` but no function is created that uses it).

In the third example, `let` scopes `i` to the block and the same thing happens except you have `i = 3;` which changes **every** `i` to `3`. So the last function that is created (as well as the previous ones which are overwritten) returns `i` which is `3`.

Answer (score 2):

> however, the above code prints 3. What is the reason for this?

Because you assign `3` to the `i` variable that `printNumTwo` closes over. It doesn't matter that the assignment happens after `printNumTwo` is created, only that it is the variable that `printNumTwo` is using.

The difference between `var` and `let` in `for` loops is that a **new** variable is created for the body of the loop on each loop iteration with `let`. But you're assigning to that variable within the loop body, so the function closing over (`printNumTwo`) it sees that value later when you call it.

It's exactly like this:

```js
function create(i) {
    // This function closes over `i`
    const fn = function() {
        return i;
    };

    // This modifies the `i` it closes over
    ++i;

    return fn;
}
const printValue1 = create(1);
console.log(printValue1()); // 2 (1 + 1)

const printValue27 = create(27);
console.log(printValue27()); // 28 (27 + 1)
```

---

In response to a comment on the question, you've said:

> same thing also happens in the second code block (i++ in the update section in for loop ) but the answer is 2

**Ah!** Now I see why there's a misunderstanding. You're right that there's an update to `i` — but it's not the `i` that `printNumTwo` closes over.

The update section of the `for` is performed on the **new** variable for the next iteration at the start of the next iteration, not on the one for the iteration that just finished at the end of the iteration. It does this:

- Create a new iteration variable (let's call it `iNew`)
- Assign the value of the old iteration variable (let's call it `iOld`) to the new variable (`iNew = iOld`)
- Run the update code using `iNew` (`iNew++`)

That's why `i` (the old one) remains `2`; it's the new one that becomes `3`.

Comment: FWIW, I go into this interesting quirk of `for` loops in detail in Chapter 2 of my recent book *JavaScript: The New Toys*. Links in my profile if you're interested.

Comment: Thanks. That makes sense now.

Answer (score 0):

**Scope of var is the function and scope of let is the block.**

So when assigning value to the `printNumTwo` function, the value of `i` is still 2. doesn't matter what happens to `i` later.

The behavior of var and let you can understand from this example.

```js
for(var i=0; i<3; i++){
    setTimeout(() => console.log('var', i))
}

for(let i=0; i < 3; i++){
    setTimeout(() => console.log('let',i))
}
```